# PowerPoint auto numbering word

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint slide that contains questions. Every slide has one question. The word "Question" is included at the top of the slide. I want to add automatic numbering behind the word "Question". I would like it to appear like: Question 1 and the next slide Question 2, etc.

I have not found a way to include an automatic number field and I am hoping for help.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint does not have a built-in feature that would do this cleanly. Microsoft Word has a SEQ field that does this, but PowerPoint does not. The only incrementing numbering that PowerPoint does is for Date & Time and Slide Number.

As a workaround you could use the Slide Number feature, which is on the Insert tab of PowerPoint. Assuming you want to begin numbering at 1, then your first slide would have to be the Question 1 slide, the second slide in the deck would have to be Question 2, and so on. In order to keep the numbering correct, the deck could not have a Title slide, and there could not be any non-question slides in-between the Question slides.

The only other option for this that I can think of, would be to write a VBA macro that controlled this and the number would be in a specially named text box on that the macro updated. The mayor would keep an internal counter and place the appropriate number into the text box.